# Laravel and Laratrust namespace not found

Tags: namespaces, laravel-5.3

I'm new to Laravel in general, and am trying to set up a seeder with the Laratrust add-on (user roles and permissions add-on). When I run `php artisan db:seed` I get an error saying `Class 'App\Role' not found` and can't figure out why it sees the Permissions class and not the Role class. My seeder looks like this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Permission;
use App\Role;

class LaratrustSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $owner = new Role();
        $owner->name         = 'owner';
        $owner->display_name = 'Project Owner';
        $owner->description  = 'User is the owner of a given project';
        $owner->save();   
    }
}
```

I have `Permission` and `Role` files in my `App` directory with this respective content:

```
namespace App;
use Laratrust\LaratrustPermission;

class Permission extends LaratrustPermission
{
    //
}
```

and

```
namespace App;
use Laratrust\LaratrustRole;

class Role extends LaratrustRole
{
    //
}
```

I've checked that my `laratrust.php` config file has `'role' => 'App\Role'` and `'permission' => 'App\Permission'` set. I've re-run `composer dump-autoload` as well just to see. Why is it seeing one and not the other?

Comment: If I just directly reference `use Laratrust\LaratrustRole;` in my seeder and use `LaratrustRole()` instead of `Role()` it works... what is wrong with my namespacing?

Comment: Everything looks ok with the information you've given. Do you perhaps have other seeders being called in `DatabaseSeeder.php`? Try running `php artisan db:seed --class=LaratrustSeeder`

Answer (score 5):

Laraturst Changed their **namespace** for **LaratrustRole** and **LaratrustPermission** in the latest version(5.0)
The correct **namespace** would be

```
Laratrust\Models\LaratrustRole;
Laratrust\Models\LaratrustPermission;
```

so you should change your code into

**app\Role**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Laratrust\Models\LaratrustRole;

class Role extends LaratrustRole
{
    //
}
```

and **app\Permission**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Laratrust\Models\LaratrustPermission;

class Permission extends LaratrustPermission
{
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update yourself on Laratrust 5.0 documentation.
Laratrust 5 namespace for Role is now *

> Laratrust\Models\LaratrustRole

And the namespace for Permission is:

> Laratrust\Models\LaratrustPermission

Update your **App\Role**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Laratrust\Models\LaratrustRole;

class Role extends LaratrustRole
{
}
```

Update your **APP\Permission**

```
namespace App;

use Laratrust\Models\LaratrustRole;

class Role extends LaratrustRole
{
}
```